# Would a more complex hash function result in a faster built table?

Tags: algorithm, hashtable

Would a simpler hash function build a Hashtable faster than a more complex one? Obviously the more complex function would build a better table that would have less collisions, but would that also translate to a faster built table since it likely didn't have to deal with as many collisions as the simpler one did?

Comment: Yes, it's a trade-off in theory, assuming that the simpler hash function results in more collisions. In practice the trade-off usually favors the better hash function since collisions cause more memory accesses and memory accesses are slow.

Answer (score -1):

So there are two things here you need to consider - `hashing time complexity` and `collision resolution time complexity`.

In general the running time of hash functions is constant or it depends linearly on the size of the input key. That being said, `constant` time does not imply it does not depend upon size of key but just the fact that if operations are being done on integers, typical computers are pretty fast today and one can treat them as a constant.

So, if you have a simpler hash function like `h(k) = k % m`, where `%` is the modulo operator, it would be faster in execution than the other functions let's say `h(k) = ( (k << 16) ^ k ) % m` where `^` is the bitwise xor operator.

Precisely the second hash function has two more integer operations than the first one, though it is still a constant. If you are running a benchmark test on a fast language like C++ and build a hash table by performing more than `100 million` inserts, the difference would be in the order of a few `milliseconds`. The exact difference would vary depending upon the hardware environment. However, the difference is for sure not going to be much.

Moreover, if you are gonna ask an experienced programmer, which would he choose among the two, I am pretty sure its going to be the second one for the fact that it is **less prone** to collisions. Please observe that any change in the last 16 bits is also going to change the higher order bits. In most of the cases, the taxing caused by collisions on performance is much more than taxing caused by computing hash values.

Also, if you are just performing insert operations, then it makes sense to use Chaining for collision resolution, as that ensures `O(1)` inserts even during collisions as opposed to probing methods. Please note that, this is only true for insert operations in hash table.
Hence, if your question just concerns building the hash table, then go with a simpler hash function with Chaining. Collisions would still be there, but the inserts will be `O(1)`

More details on hash tables and how to avoid high running time complexity for collisions can be found [here](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/62393).